# Kotlin dataclasses inside sealed class

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-android-extensions

I am new to kotlin. I am trying to handle errors in rxjava with kotlin. For that i have written following sealed class and some extension.

```
sealed class Result<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error<out T>(val t: Throwable) : Result<T>()
}
```

How to instantiate Result? Since its sealed class i am unable to do so. Following are the extensions that i have written.

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.retrofitResponseToResult(): Observable<Result<T>> {
    return this.map { it.asResult() }
            .onErrorReturn {
                if (it is HttpException || it is IOException) {
                    return@onErrorReturn it.asErrorResult<T>()
                } else {
                    throw it
                }
            }
}

fun <T> T.asResult(): Result<T> {
    return Result(data = this, error = null)
}

fun <T> Throwable.asErrorResult(): Result<T> {
    return Result(data = null, error = this)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sealed classes are abstract and cannot be instantiated. You should rather instantiate `Success` or `Error` instead.

```
fun <T> T.asResult(): Result<T> {
    return Result.Success(this)
}

fun <T> Throwable.asErrorResult(): Result<T> {
    return Result.Error(this)
}
```

Sealed Classes are a tool for providing restricted class hierarchies.

Comment: Ah nice, Thank you.

Comment: I did as you suggested in my code i am expecting return type ```Observable<Result<WSResponse>>``` from ```.retrofitResponseToResult()``` but it returns ```Observable<Result<Result<WSResponse>>>``` this looks strange to me.